How to expand the size of root partition using LVM using with multiple disks?
Following is the sliced output of lsblk:
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0 341.8G  0 part /media/user/sda1
├─sda2        8:2    0   293G  0 part /media/user/sda2
└─sda3        8:3    0 296.7G  0 part /media/user/sda3
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 237.4G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                      /

As you can see nvme0n1p2 is the root partition and almost full whereas sda{1,2,3} have enough space : (output of df -h, sliced for readability)
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2  233G  225G  3G    97% /
/dev/sda1       336G   10G  309G   3% /media/user/sda1
/dev/sda2       288G   28K  273G   1% /media/user/sda2
/dev/sda3       292G   28K  277G   1% /media/user/sda3

My question is :

What could be the best way (if possible) to increase the size of root
partition for eg by 'x' gigs using storage of 'sda' disk ?

I've heard and searched about LVM. I found some folks discussing about creating logical volumes using multiple diks. In my glimpse of reading some threads in the internet, I could not find (or I could not confirm/deny as I am no expert to it) playing with the root partition with multiple disks using LVM.
So, for time being, I just want to expand root partition using LVM as it should be one of the best way for managing disks (following steps to do so) and begin working on the machine (leaving advanced learning for later).
Apology for not sounding technical enough. Hope you guys understand the problem though.

You probably cannot make use of LVM without a full reinstall. The  amount of space in use by / is quite a lot. I’d recommend looking at what is using that space and see if you can recover it or reorganise things . It might solve your problem by moving /home to a partition on sda
